# How add style sheet to content of <browser> element in Firefox?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

How add style sheet to  content of  element in Firefox?
This not working:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/stylesheet_utils
Skips element content of  element.

Comment: Do you mean how to add CSS to an individual HTML element?

Comment: Specifically it for content of sidebar with bookmarks: browser#sidebar[src=chrome://browser/content/bookmarks/bookmarksPanel.xul]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> loadSheet(window, uri, type)
> content of <browser> element
>
> if browserElement is xul browser element,
> then browserElement.contentWindow is a window (or nsIDOMWindow)
>
> loadSheet(browserElement.contentWindow, uri, type)
> ```

It works. Just like switching off and switching on the sidebar, it's already this style does not load
sidebarWindow.addEventListener("load", function() {console.log("sidebear.test");});